# how do I prepend an integer in an array of strings using ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array created by the following ruby code in a method:

```
array[i] = {:key => response.body['results'][i]['path']['key'],  
              :value => response.body['results'][i]['value'],
              :epoch_time => response.body['results'][i]['path']['reftime'] / 1000}
array[i][:collection] = response.body['results'][i]['path']['collection']
```

I would like another method `.enumerate_array` or something which goes through an appends "i -" which i is the corresponding index value of the array.

For example, for `array[0][:value] = "this was the first answer"`.

Then:

`array = enumerate_array(array)`

`=> array[0][:value] = "0 - this was the first answer"`

Thanks.

Comment: [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) will help you to fetch index of an array

Comment: Thank you -- I am trying to assess which solution to use....from those below.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the following array with hashes:

```
[{ value: "foo" }, { value: "bar" }, { value: "baz" }]
```

And you would want the following output:

```
[{ value: "0 - foo" }, { value: "1 - bar" }, { value: "2 - baz" }]
```

You could do something like this:

```
def enumerate_array(array)
  array.each_with_index do |hash, index|
    hash[:value] = "#{index} - #{hash[:value]}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Making copies of original hashes:

```
def enumerate_array(array)
  array.map.with_index { |h, i| h.merge({value: "#{i} - #{h[:value]}"}) }
end
```

Altering original hashes:

```
def enumerate_array!(array)
  array.each_with_index { |h, i| h[:value] = "#{i} - #{h[:value]}" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{ value: "dog" }, { value: "cat" }, { value: "pig" }]
```

If `arr` is to be mutated:

```
arr.each_index { |i| arr[i][:value] = "#{i} - #{arr[i][:value] }" }
  #=> [{:value=>"0 - dog"}, {:value=>"1 - cat"}, {:value=>"2 - pig"}] 
arr
  #=> [{:value=>"0 - dog"}, {:value=>"1 - cat"}, {:value=>"2 - pig"}]
```

If `arr` is not to be mutated (after resetting `arr`):

```
arr.each_index.with_object([]) { |i,a| a << { value: "#{i} - #{arr[i][:value] }" } }
  #=> [{:value=>"0 - dog"}, {:value=>"1 - cat"}, {:value=>"2 - pig"}] 
arr 
  #=> [{:value=>"dog"}, {:value=>"cat"}, {:value=>"pig"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def enumerate_array(array)
  array.each_with_index do |hash, index|
      hash.each_pair { |key, value| hash[key] = "#{index} - #{value}" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ruby 2.x, you can chain map and with_index to make it a one-liner:

```
array = array.map.with_index { |item, index| "#{index} - #{item}" }
```

Comment: Won't this cause array to hold only strings instead of hash?, this way array elements will be mapped to strings.

Comment: If you copied it exactly. Whatever is returned from the block is set in the array. Modify it to return what you need.